# Position custom form error in different responsive modes

Tags: html, css, validation, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap navigation, with a form to the right. I also have a custom error box, that I want to display at the bottom of the form in the browser like so.

[image]
However in responsive mode, it displays like this: 
[image]
Due to the error box being an absolute positioned element, I want to know how can I make it display better as it gets responsive for mobile and tablet?

The error box should display like the first image, but the error box should display before the search(forgot to change to login) button in mobile/tablet.

I am not using jqueryvalidation. These errors will be outputted in .net core, but positioning them are a pain for me at the moment.

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 240px;
}

.arr {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-0">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="password">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <div class="error">
          <div class="arr"></div>
          <p>error box with validation</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.navbar-collapse{
position:relative
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 240px;
}

.arr {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-0">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="password">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <div class="error">
          <div class="arr"></div>
          <p>error box with validation</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: position absolute is fine for the desktop version I think, but how do I style it for when its in mobile and tablet mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a small edit...now error box stands at bottom without any shift..but it does not point to correct form element still...

```css
.navbar {
  min-height: 70px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.navbar-brand {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 55px;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border: 0 !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:active,
.navbar-toggler:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  border-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -55px;
  right: 240px;
}
form {
  position:relative;
  }

.arr {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  margin-left: 80px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid blue;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
}

@media (max-width:574px) {
   .error {
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  right: 240px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-0">
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">

      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="password" aria-label="password">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <div class="error">
          <div class="arr"></div>
          <p>error box with validation</p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think position absolute is fine for desktop, but how can I position it better when its in mobile and tablet?

Comment: Done using @media query..plzchk it